# Where is the Facebook API Key in the new layout?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, api-key

well I'm just wondering where the facebook api key went, now all I see is the secret and the app id. But nowhere can I find the api key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app ID and API key are the same thing. If you go to the Developer app and click on one of your applications, you'll see the label is "App ID/API Key".